# Fuerte sensor_msgs::Joy Changed?

Tags: ros, c++, sensor-msgs, ros-fuerte, joy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

~/ros/p2os/p2os_teleop/src/p2os_teleop.cc:169:64: error: ‘const struct sensor_msgs::Joy_std::allocator<void >’ has no member named ‘get_axes_size’

Am I missing something or what? This program built fine in ROS-E..

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32775/fuerte-sensor_msgs::joy-changed?/) by [Dereck](https://answers.ros.org/users/2254/dereck/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1070 on 2012-04-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This not only affects sensor_msgs::Joy but all messages. All get_...*size and set*..._size functions were already deprecated and are now removed in favor of the standard vector API. See [Fuerte migration](http://ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Migration#error:_XXX_has_no_member_named_.27set_YYY_size.27_.28or_.27get_YYY_size.27.29).

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2012-04-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3